Two duplicated names in a generated Typescript file
One of the generated file, foo-service-update.component.ts, in my project contains the following lines of Typescript code:
import { type IFooService, FooService } from '@/shared/model/foo-service.model';

export default defineComponent({
  compatConfig: { MODE: 3 },
  name: 'FooServiceUpdate',
  setup() {
    ...

    const fooService: Ref<IFooService> = ref(new FooService());

    const fooService = inject('fooService', () => new FooService());
    ...
});

The last two lines cause an error
The symbol "fooService" has already been declared

After some investigations, I locate the source of this error in relationship
relationship ManyToOne {
    FooService to Foo
}

Without this relationship, the error won't occur.
